# Error de traducción en la página de ayuda sobre cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable

Tags: bug, traducciones

Me acabo de dar cuenta al referir a alguien a la página de ayuda [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que reduzca la cantidad de código en su pregunta, de que la página dice lo siguiente bajo el subtema **Mínimo**:

> Mientras más código haya, ***se eleva la probabilidad*** de que la gente encuentre tu problema.

En realidad, debería decir lo contrario, tal vez algo como:

> Mientras más código haya, ***será menos probable*** que la gente encuentre tu problema.

A modo de comparación, esto es lo que dice la [versión en inglés de la misma página](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

> The more code there is to go through, the ***less likely*** people can find your problem.